# Trigger function with a delay longer than an hour in a Node/Express app

Tags: node.js, express, promise, settimeout

I would like to trigger a function in my express app with a delay of 1 hour or 5 hours after a specific endpoint was called.

I've tried using a simple `setTimeout` in the `then` chain of my enpoint with something like this in my controller:

```
function(req, res, next) {

  return mailer.sendEmail(req.user, 'firstEmail') // returns a promise
  .then(function(emailResult) {
    if (emailResult == 'ok') {
       res.sendStatus(200).json({ message: 'You will receive an email in 1 hour' }) // set positive API json response
    } else {
       res.sendStatus(200).json({ message: 'You will receive an email in 5 hour' }) // set negative API json response
    }
    return emailResult
  })
  .then(function(emailResult){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function(){
            return return mailer.sendEmail(req.user, 'secondEmail')
        }, emailResult == 'ok' ? 60 * 60 * 1000 : 5 * 60 * 60 * 1000) // 1 hour or 5 hours
    })
  }) 
})
```

and seems to work but I have two main dubts:

- If I restart the pm2 process of my application with (pm2 startOrReload prod.json), all the timeouts are cancelled?
- If I have something like 600 timeouts scheduled with this system can I have any performance issues?

Any experience with something like this?

Comment: You should probably consider some sort of dedicated queue for this, like [kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue).

Comment: seems a good choice, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: At the end I decided to use kue to manage jobs and delay them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeout like this might be a solution but not the very best kind.

If timeouts are instantly adding to your memory, like every hour, when you restart your Node.js process the timers yet to trigger are lost, and that means you can not restart your App even when you are trying to update the new code if you don't want to lose any of them. Losing emails or never restart, a little bit of confusion, right?

The most frequently implemented approach for such a case is Message Queue.
You can take Message Queue as timers that stored and consumed in a database, so you don't have to worry about whether timers are canceled or called multiple times when you don't want that happen.

RabbitMQ is a standalone MQ that is friendly to Node.js.

Kue is an MQ-like NPM package that relies on Redis.

Hope you like'em. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I already faced this issue.

The solution I found is to use my database as the time register.
Basically, if you are using SQL or Document oriented database:

1. Insert a scheduled action into the database.
2. Check every x seconds (depend on the accuracy you need) if there is an entry which need to be popped. If so, delete the item, take it, execute it.

You could also use `cron` package to do the check, but... since this is simple to be implemented, you should do it by yourself.

EDIT: Why this solution?

First, this is RAM saver for server, when you have like 5000 entries, you don't have to store it in the memory.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes all your timeout will be cancelled as they are memory stored
- i don't think having 600 timeout might be an issue but you may find better suitable method like having an array with all your timeouts sorted and a setInterval to check if there's a need to execute something.